# Python realtime plot, re-update

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to have two plots (#1, #2). I want to update the plot #1 as data is coming up, and then update plot #2 as well. After this, I might want to go back and update plot #1. However, I am unable to update plot #1. Any help?

Here are my source code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random(10)
b = np.random.random(10)

plt.subplot(311)
for i in range (10):
    y = a[i]
    x = b[i]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.05)



plt.subplot(312)
for i in range (10):
    x = a[i]
    y = b[i]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.05)

# update plot #1, but this doesn't work
aa = np.random.random(20)
bb = np.random.random(20)
plt.subplot(311)
for i in range (20):
    y = aa[i]
    x = bb[i]
    plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.subplot` is for creating new subplots. If you want to access different subplots not only directly after creating them, choose

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
```

for creating the figure with all subplots first.
Then you can plot with

```
axs[0].plot(...)
axs[1].plot(...)
axs[0].plot(...)
```

The same works with `plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)` for a 2D-array of plots. Then `axs` is also a 2D-array.

Besides that, `plt.subplots` has a very convenient way to define shared axes via the kwargs `sharex` and `sharey`, which can be one of `['all', 'row', 'col', 'none']`.